# How to read a list from a properties file?

Tags: java, annotations

In my `abc.properties` file I have a list

```
xyz=cat,dog,cow,calf
```

I want to read that from my java code.

I tried `@Value` annotation

```
 @Value("${xyz}")  private String[] elementToSearch;
```

But clearly I am doing something wrong because when I print `elementToSearch[0]` I get `${xyz}`
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where does that `@Value` annotation come from?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use the @Value annotation from the Spring framework.

Actually, I think you're doing it right.  Is possible you don't have a PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer in play?

Most of the time I've seen it done by adding something like this to your Spring applicationContext.xml configuration file:

```
    <!-- if you are using annotations -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- if you are scanning for annotated beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.package" />


<!-- Load override configuration from a property file. --> 
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:abc.properties</value>
                <value>file:/etc/someplace/abc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```